# Cheap bendable material for DIY project

Tags: garage

I'm looking into making a DIY indoor mini golf course. I want to possibly make some curved surfaces (ramp, bridge, curved walls). I'm looking for a cheap material that can bend smoothly, but is kinda strong. At most it needs to be able to stay still from a golf ball rolling on it, so it doesn't need to be too strong.

I just had the idea, that i would nail/tape it to the wood/floor. I also do not want anything that would require a cutting saw or any heavier duty tools.

Can someone point me in the correct direction?

---

The material used to support legal pads would be good (chipboard i think?), now i just need it in large sheets.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. I'd suggest going to your local big box hardware store and just wanter the aisles. There's all sorts of materials that will likely fit your needs...metals, woods, plastics, etc.

Comment: Probably what i'll end up doing. But i wanted at least an idea of what i would be looking for. The material used to support legal pads would be good (chipboard i think?), now i just need it in larger sheets.

Comment: Do you mean the cardboard backs of notepads? That's not something you'd find at the hardware store. That's a more of an office/art supply product.

Comment: sheet aluminum?

Comment: Mini-golf courses are sculpted concrete with turf over them; how is whatever you're going to use be OK to stand on?

Comment: @Mazura it isn't supposed to be permanent. Just a quick project that i can asssemble and when done, throw most things away.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like sodium acrylate or polycarbonate (lexan) would work. Unlike acrylic sheets (plexiglass glass) the two I mentioned are less brittle and easier to fasten with screws and drilled holes. These materials can all be cut with a specialized handheld plastic cutter that looks like a razor.

The cost will depend on the thickness of material, but given that they're strong you could probably get away with bracing thinner sheets.

Comment: "*I'm looking for a cheap material*". No way Lexan meets that requirement.

Comment: Well to be fair, the original question never specified price range nor expected quantity. If you buy thin sheets in bulk then it can be affordable

Answer (score 0):

Masonite or luan plywood.  Either can be cut by scoring with a utility knife, and it bends very well.

Cardboard can also be bent into curves if it is kind of crushed along a line so it bends, like the flaps on a box.  I use the back of a scissor blade or the round end of a ballpoint pen to sort of score it without breaking the paper.

To get the curved profile on the edge of the unbent edge of the ramp, it helps to trace the curve from a yardstick or piece of molding bent to get the desired profile.